# Can we predict the time it will take to brute-force a word given the length of the word and the set of chars to look into?

Tags: javascript, math, brute-force

Is there a way to predict (approximately) how long it would take to brute-force amongst a pool of **P** chars looking for a string of **N** chars long ?

Would it also help the calculation if we knew that in that pool of **P** chars, **X** number of them are actually used in the word and the rest of them are irrelevant ?

```
let pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'
let word = 'polkadpark'
let result = await bruteForce({ inside: pool, for: word }) 
// `result` should now be equal to `word`
```

Comment: There are a *lot* more variables that go into this calculation than simply the target string and the pool of characters. Processor speed, processor quantity, number of threads on each processor... and I’m sure I’m leaving off quite a few.

Comment: Use math to calculate how many different possible words an be produced from the pool.

Comment: Then if you know how long it takes to test each possibility, you multiply the number of possible words by the time per word. Then divide by half to get the average number of tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of instructions of one interation * (Length of pool) ^ (Length of word) 
___________________________________________________________________________
 (number of instructions per second * number of threads used)